# Scroll to top of Android list, even where there are non-focusable elements at the top

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RecyclerView that displays content in grid sections, where each grid section is headed by a non-interactive TextView (nothing happens if you click/tap on it).

[image]

If I am navigating the screen in non-touch mode (using only keyboard/remote/trackball), then clearly I'll need a focus state:

[image]

If I navigate downwards through the RecyclerView such that "SECTION 1" is off-screen, then back up again - scrolling will stop at the top grid item under Section 1, then the next focused item will be the hamburger menu; **SECTION 1 will still be offscreen** because it's not focusable - it won't have scrolled to top.

In touch-mode, this is not an issue; the user can scroll back up. In non-touch-mode, I can make the section headings focusable - but it doesn't make sense semantically to have these non-interactive elements to have a focus state (leaving aside accessibility services like TalkBack - if TalkBack is enabled, sure, they can be focusable).

Without setting the section headers focusable, is there any way to ensure, when using the trackball to navigate up the list, that it scrolls to the top of the list (including the section headers) before focusing on the next element (hamburger menu)?

---

Here is the code for a single RecyclerView item - this consists of the entire section: the non-interactive section header, and 3 interactive elements below. `android:focusable="false"` is shown to highlight the problem (the default case is false).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/category_text_heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This picture illustrates the problem:

[image]

Here the hamburger icon is focused, but the RecyclerView has not scrolled to the top of the content. If I make "SECTION 1" focusable, then using the keyboard/trackball to navigate up will allow "SECTION 1" to receive focus, and all focusable elements are moved into view, so it'll scroll to the top, before pressing up again, to focus on the hamburger icon.

Comment: phhht no code example

Comment: @Blundell added XML for a RecyclerView item - the Adapter manages a list of Sections, each of which has 3 sub items.

Comment: did you find any solution to this yet?I am having the same problem

Comment: @NishanKhadka no I haven't. I suspect there could be a lead with pre-rendering of off-screen items in RecyclerView.

Comment: Also have a similar issue but using a collipsing toolbar, you scroll down, the toolbar collipses at some point as expect and when returning up with TalkBack the toolbar won't appear, instead it will jump to the hamburger menu. I think there are still many Android bugs regarding focus navigation.

Comment: @david this might help https://ataulm.com/2018/03/04/collapsing-appbarlayout-on-android-tv/

Comment: Thanks @ataulm, I solved it but simply making the appbar no collipsible while Accessibility is detected, this works fine as blind people won't mind. In your blog post don't know why you had a list item not showing up completely, never had that issue and don't think that should be an issue today anymore.

Comment: yeah the blog post was originally written in 2015 so might be different now.